# Java version of the mongo query to retrive unique string from array along with the count

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongo-java-driver

DB :
the array is just a collection of strings, which could repeat. And I am trying to retrieve all strings along with the count of their use

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([ 
{$unwind:"$array"}, 
{$group:{"_id":"$array","count":{$sum:1}}}, 
{$group:{"_id":null,"array_details":{$push:{"name":"$_id", "count":"$count"}}}}, 
{$project:{"_id":0,"array_details":1}} 
])
```

So far i have this

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
            Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("array").exists(true)),
            Aggregation.unwind("array"),
            Aggregation.group("array"),



    );
```

Comment: So, all you want is to convert the shell into java query?

Comment: Here are some examples of using the [Spring Data MongoDB Aggregation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation).

Answer (score 0):

Found out. Thanks for the suggestions guys

```
                Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("array").exists(true)),
            Aggregation.unwind("array"),
            Aggregation.group("array").count().as("count"),
            Aggregation.project().andExpression("_id").as("title")
                    .andExpression("count").as("count")

    );
```